# jQuery not working on Ajax loaded div content

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a div on my page which checked by ajax and content loaded based on a MySQL query result.

jQuery which has been loaded on-page is not working for the ajax updated content.

The jQuery code I am using is as follows

```
function getLiveStreamAuction() {
        
            var ajaxurl = saajaxurl+'=get_live_stream_auction';
        
        jQuery.ajax({

            type : "post",
            encoding:"UTF-8",
            url : ajaxurl,
            dataType: 'json',
            data : {action: "get_live_stream_auction", "last_activity" : SA_last_activity},
            success: function(response) {
            console.log("success");
            jQuery(".woocommerce-live-stream-container").replaceWith(response.screen_text);
            },
            error: function(response){
                console.log("fail");
            }
        });
}
```

It is like jQuery is not applicable for the updated content and I could not find a workaround so far. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: What specifically isn't working? Also what does `response.screen_text` look like?

Comment: jQuery functions will not work on the elements that were not present (like ones loaded using ajax) when the page loaded originally, unless the function is called after loading the contents from ajax.

Answer (score 0):

As quoted by always a learner, jQuery functions defined at window load is not applicable for the content loaded by an ajax call. After calling the necessary functions after ajax call, everything run as it should be and problem solved. Thanks a lot.